# Collapse and jump to top of div

Tags: jquery, html, css

When a collapsed div is expanded to show the rest of the content, it pushes the rest of the content on the page down. This is fine.
When "read less" is clicked, the content moves back up, leaving the user at an unknown spot in the page. 
I would like to jump to the top of the parent div when its collapsed.

Trying to implement some code I found in another SO article but failing:

```
$('#A_ID').click(function (e) { //#A_ID is an example. Use the id of your Anchor
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#DIV_ID').offset().top - 20 //#DIV_ID is an example. Use the id of your destination on the page
    }, 'slow');
});
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text').each(function(element,index){
        if($(this)[0].scrollHeight>$(this).height()){
            $(this).next().show()
        }else{
            $(this).next().hide()
        }
    })
})

function changeheight(obj) {
        var fullHeight = $(obj).parent().prev().get(0).scrollHeight        
        var readmore = $(obj);
        if (readmore.text() == 'Read more') {
            readmore.text("Read less");
            $(obj).parent().prev().data('oldHeight',$(obj).parent().prev().height())
            $(obj).parent().prev().animate({'height':fullHeight},500)
        } else {
            readmore.text("Read more");
           $(obj).parent().prev().animate({'height':$(obj).parent().prev().data('oldHeight')},500)
        }           
    };
```

[Full Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/dc13afhq/)

On the fiddle, if you click 'read more' in the red area and then scroll down to click 'read less', you are left at the bottom of the page rather than the top of the red div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$(obj).parent().prev().animate({'height':$(obj).parent().prev().data('oldHeight')},500)`

This statement only change the div's height, so your page will stay the same `scollY`, which results that it seems page scroll down.

So what you need to do is scroll the page manually.

Just change your `changeheight` function to this: (add a statement in `else`)

```js
function changeheight(obj) {
        var fullHeight = $(obj).parent().prev().get(0).scrollHeight   
        var readmore = $(obj);
        if (readmore.text() == 'Read more') {
            readmore.text("Read less");
            $(obj).parent().prev().data('oldHeight',$(obj).parent().prev().height())
            $(obj).parent().prev().animate({'height':fullHeight},350)
        } else {
           readmore.text("Read more");
           $(obj).parent().prev().animate({'height':$(obj).parent().prev().data('oldHeight')}, 350); 
           $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(obj).parent().prev().offset().top }, 350);
        }           
    };
```

> `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(obj).parent().prev().offset().top }, 350);`

This statement will help you to scroll top to the corresponding div.

**BTW**, it's not recommanded that use same `id` (in your code is `text`).

Comment: Thanks, I started getting close but couldn't quite get it. This works perfectly!